# How to organize API results in alphabetical order with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I am using jQuery to make an AJAX call to pull data from an API -

```
const generateFilterOptions = () => {
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: baseURL,
}).done(function (data, status, xhr) {
    let category = [];
    let categoryID = [];
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        category.push(value.field_resource_category);
        categoryID.push(value.field_resource_category_id);
    })
    category = [...new Set(category.toString().split(',').map(el => el.trim()))];
    categoryID = [...new Set(categoryID.toString().split(',').map(el => el.trim()))];
    category.forEach(
        (categoryName, id) =>
            $("#categoryFilter").append(`
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="${categoryName}" value="${categoryID[id]}" id="cat-${categoryID[id]}">
                        <label class="fs-6" for="cat-${categoryID[id]}">${categoryName}</label>
                    </div>
                    `)
    );
});
```

}

The values being returned are 1 to 2 digit numbers, and many of them are duplicates because it's pulling the ID of a category, and many of the results share the same category.

The markup must include the name that being pulled, as well as the category ID, and it is for a filter so the results cannot be duplicated.

```
category.push(value.field_resource_category);
categoryID.push(value.field_resource_category_id);
```

I start by pushing the values into their own arrays

```
category = [...new Set(category.toString().split(',').map(el => el.trim()))];
categoryID = [...new Set(categoryID.toString().split(',').map(el => el.trim()))];
```

Then I use Set() to remove any duplicates. toString() to change from array to a string, split() to remove the comma, then .map with .trim() to remove whitespace

```
category.forEach(
    (categoryName, id) =>
        $("#categoryFilter").append(`
            <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                <input type="checkbox" name="${categoryName}" value="${categoryID[id]}" id="cat-${categoryID[id]}">
                <label class="fs-6" for="cat-${categoryID[id]}">${categoryName}</label>
            </div>
        `)
);
```

Then I have a for each loop that returns the name and ID so I can put it into my HTML markup.

I need to manipulate the results so that they are in alphabetical order.

I tried to add in .sort(), but the problem is the ID that's being returned is a string not a number, so 11 comes before 2 in alphabetical order

Answer (score 1):

You can sort number strings by converting them to numbers and subtracting one from the other to determine their order.

```js
const x = [
  "21",
  "1",
  "2000",
  "11",
  "132",
].sort((a, b) => Number(a) - Number(b));

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

even shorter than @ray's solution:

```js
const x = [
  "21",
  "1",
  "2000",
  "11",
  "132",
].sort((a, b) =>a-b);

console.log(x);
```

The strings are automatically translated to numbers depending on the operation that's being done. You don't need to worry. That's called type coersion and though controversial it's a 'feature' of Javascript.
Just be aware of edge cases: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/ch04.html
(check section "Edge cases")

Comment: This occurred to me and I can't really say why I decided to be explicit about the casting.